# Why Hibernate second level cache perform put action at each call and takes lots of time?

Tags: spring, hibernate, caching, hazelcast, boot

I have a spring boot 2.7.3 application that uses hibernate, hazelcast as a second level cache factory, mysql. My aim is to use second level cache at find all query and make query faster.
There is about 5012 entity in database for development purpose.

To problem here I face is that when I run first findAll method It takes every entity from database and put them to second level cache. However, after second query it hits only 30 of them and puts missed ones to cache again. Thus, this put process takes lots of time and slower the system. When I close the second level cache, funny but system works faster.

My application.yml file:

```
    properties:
      hibernate.jdbc.time_zone: UTC
      hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true
      hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit: true
      hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
      hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
      hibernate.generate_statistics: false
      # modify batch size as necessary
      hibernate.jdbc.batch_size: 25
      hibernate.order_inserts: true
      hibernate.order_updates: true
      hibernate.query.fail_on_pagination_over_collection_fetch: true
      hibernate.query.in_clause_parameter_padding: true
      hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: com.hazelcast.hibernate.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory
```

I added annotation for `@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)` to entity class to make it cacheable.

My Hazelcast config:

```
    @Bean
    public Config hazelcastConfig() {
 
        Config config = new Config();
        config.setInstanceName("placeholder");

        MapConfig mapConfig = new MapConfig("default");
        mapConfig.setBackupCount(1);
        mapConfig.getEvictionConfig().setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU);
        mapConfig.getEvictionConfig().setMaxSizePolicy(MaxSizePolicy.USED_HEAP_SIZE);
        mapConfig.setTimeToLiveSeconds(3600);
        config.addMapConfig(mapConfig);

        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
    }
```

I have a very basic find all method:

```
    public List<SinkSourceAddDTO> findAll() {
        return HouseRepository.findAll()
       .stream().map(HouseAddMapper::toDto)
       .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
    }
```

Session metrics:
First method call:

```
Session Metrics {
    1968100 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    41430100 nanoseconds spent preparing 32 JDBC statements;
    52658900 nanoseconds spent executing 32 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    2712459300 nanoseconds spent performing 5012 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    8894900 nanoseconds spent performing 30 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    97100 nanoseconds spent executing 2 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

Puts 5012 entries to cache.

Second, third and so on method call:

```
Session Metrics {
    290100 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    111100 nanoseconds spent preparing 2 JDBC statements;
    14781000 nanoseconds spent executing 2 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    1450759900 nanoseconds spent performing 4982 L2C puts;
    9978700 nanoseconds spent performing 30 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    11100 nanoseconds spent executing 2 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

Only hits 30 of them and puts remainings to cache and this take 1.4 s to complete.

I tried lots of things such as migrating EhCache, increase cache size, increase time to live, chance eviction policy etc. but none of them works and fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is to provide some guidance to your question. I know it is not a direct answer because it is impossible to say something without seeing your environment

1. Say your L2 cache size is around 5012 items. It may grow over this size if necessary. Expiration and eviction are best effort based.
2. When findAll() is executed it will try to put items that **don't exist** in the L2 cache. If it exists, Hibernate will assume that L2 has the latest value and skip this item. That's why we **should not** update the DB behind Hibernate's back. Anyway findAll() is **not** L2 hit. As a result you will see **"performing ... L2C puts;"** logs. As a side note findAll() call result can be cached in **Query Cache** But that is a different topic.
3. When findById() is executed it will try to find the item from L2 cache. This is L2 hit. As a result you will see **"performing ... L2C hits;"** logs

From your logs we can probably deduce that

- something is executing 30 findById() statements. Hence you have L2 hits
- and something is calling findAll(). Hence you have L2 puts and some items are already in L2.
- And lastly remember that L2 is a key-value store. You can get a hit only if accessed by key